# LINQ Agrupar Columna 1 y Sumar Columna 2 de un DataTable

Tags: linq

Tengo un proceso donde se generan valores repetidos, por ejemplo: 1=20, 1=80, 1=50, 2=100, 2=30, etc... Estos lo envío a un DataTable de VB .Net 2015.
La primera columna la llamo "No" y la segunda se llama "Cantidad"; he intentado de muchas formas y no consigo con LINQ, la estructura correcta para que agrupe la Columna "No" y me proporcione la Suma que corresponde a la Agrupación.
¿Me pueden ayudar, por favor?

Comment: Y podrías poner esos.intentos quizás en alguno de ellos estas bien cerca y por otro lado te podríamos ayudar a visualizar que te falto. Aparte que tu pregunta no aporta mucho.

Comment: La idea del sitio es poder dar una respuesta precisa a tu pregunta y es responsabilidad tuya facilitar la recreación de tu problema, idealmente y casi obligatorio que yo pueda copiar tu código, modificar lo que haya que modificar y entregarte una solución. En tu caso tengo que imaginarme las clases, las propiedades y que rayos quisiste decir con 1=20, 1=80, etc

Comment: sin algo de codigo no hay mucho que hacer, solo suponer y no se llega a nada, por cierto la bolita de cristal esta en el taller por eso no respondo con una respuesta XD

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como hacer el linq, como no se que campos usas ni nada he hecho de bolita de cristal y he supuesto que los dos campos eran int aunque no tendría que variar.

Codigo principal:

```
 //Cargo datos a mano
        List<Datos> datos= new List<Datos>();
        datos.Add(new Datos(1,20));
        datos.Add(new Datos(1, 80));
        datos.Add(new Datos(1, 50));
        datos.Add(new Datos(2, 100));
        datos.Add(new Datos(2, 30));

      datos=  datos.GroupBy(item => item.No).Select(item => new Datos    //crear un nuevo dato ya agrupado
        {
            No = item.Key, //la clave es el valor del No agrupado 
            Cantidad = item.ToList().Select(gc => gc.Cantidad).Sum() //suma la cantidad de la agrupacion
        }).ToList();
       foreach (Datos datos1 in datos)//imprimo el resultado
        Console.WriteLine(datos1.ToString());
       Console.ReadLine();
```

Clase datos:

```
 class Datos//classe que alberga los datos
    {
        public Datos()//necessario tener uno declarado para el group by
        {

        }
        public Datos(int no, int cantidad) {//para el principio
            this.No = no;
            this.Cantidad = cantidad;
        
        
        
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return No.ToString()+","+Cantidad.ToString();
        }
        public int No { get; set; }
        public int Cantidad { get; set; }
    }
```

Comanda de linq separada del codigo:

```
  datos=  datos.GroupBy(item => item.No).Select(item => new Datos    //crear un nuevo dato ya agrupado
            {
                No = item.Key, //la clave es el valor del No agrupado 
                Cantidad = item.ToList().Select(gc => gc.Cantidad).Sum() //suma la cantidad de la agrupacion
            }).ToList();
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Muy agradecido por las respuestas...

Me funciona muy bien hasta el Group By, pero al agregar Group.Sum por la columna Cn01 de la DataTable, ya no muestra ningún dato y recibo el Error 13.

La verdad, soy novato con LINQ, por lo que me acerco a Ustedes, ya que también es mi primera publicación en éste sitio... Éste es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
Dim UltimaConsulta = (From Tbl01 In DTable01
Group Tbl01 By LaEsfera = Tbl01.Field(Of Integer)("No01") "Into Group
Select New With {Key LaEsfera, .Cant = Group.Sum(Function(r) 
r.Field(Of Long)("Cn01"))})
```

Éstas son las Columnas del DataTable y los valores por fila y en cada campo

```
| No01 | Cn01 |
  ------------
1      68
1      31
2      10
2      15
3      21

Al final, el resultado LINQ debe ser
1 = 99
2 = 25
3 = 21
```

¡Gracias!